# Return Row when criteria from two columns is correct

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets: I need to return a row based on searches in two columns (each column has repeating data). Column A has a list of dates with duplicate dates. Column B has a list of names with repeating data. I need to return the row when I get a match from the date and name. This row is returning to another sheet in the same sheets document.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:C,"select * where A=date '2015-01-01' and B='A' ")
```

where the date of interest is taken as Jan 1, 2015 the name of interest `A` and the assumption made that in addition to ColumnsA:B data you also want the corresponding ColumnC values.